# SQL - Query to compare the exact number and content of strings

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join

I want to write a query that returns pairs of books (f_DOI, s_DOI), which respect the following criterion: the keywords associated with s_DOI (second book) are ALL also associated with f_DOI (first book).

**Keywords**

```
Doi   Keyword
1     'Adventure'
2     'Adventure'
1     'Fantasy'
2     'Thriller'
3     'Football'
4     'Football'
5     'History'
```

This is my code:

```
select k1.doi f_DOI , k2.doi s_DOI, k1.keyword
from keywords k1
join keywords k2
   on k2.doi > k1.doi
where k1.keyword= k2.keyword;
```

This is my output:

```
f_DOI s_DOI  KEYWORD
1     2     Adventure
3     4     Football
```

The first row is not correct, how you can see the f_DOI = 1 and s_DOI = 2 have in common only the 'Adventure' keyword the other two are different (How you can see in the table Keyword DOI = 1 have also keyword 'fantasy' and DOI = 2 have keyword 'thriller').

Comment: Nothing is called `f_doi` in your sample data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  f_doi and s_doi are the aliases that I entered to facilitate their reading when I do the inner join, in my table it is indicated as DOI.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you seem to want the second to be a super set of the first.  That would be:

```
with k as (
      select k.*, count(*) over (partition by doi) as cnt
      from keywords k
     )
select k.doi, k2.doi
from k join
     k k2
     on k2.keyword = k.keyword
group by k.doi, k2.doi, k.cnt
having count(*) = k.cnt;
```

If you want exact matches, then include `k2.cnt = k.cnt` in the `on` clause.

(And this assumes no duplicates.)

EDIT:

You can get the exact same keywords using:

```
with k as (
      select k.*, count(*) over (partition by doi) as cnt
      from (select distinct keyword, doi from keywords k) k
     )
select k.doi, k2.doi
from k join
     k k2
     on k2.keyword = k.keyword and k2.cnt = k.cnt
group by k.doi, k2.doi, k.cnt
having count(*) = k.cnt;
```

Or the `listagg()` approach:

```
select keywords, listagg(doi, ',') within group (order by keyword)
from (select doi,
            listagg(keyword, ',') within group (order by keyword) as keywords
      from (select distinct doi, keyword from keywords) k
      group by doi
     ) d
group by keywords;
```

This can be limited by Oracle's limitations on string length.

Comment: I tried this query and it seems to work (except for the duplicates that I have [1 1, 3 3, etc ...] also adding on the clause on k2.cnt = k.cnt). However surely I was unclear in the request, sorry for this, what I am trying to get from my query is to have the following result: DOI 3 and 4, because are the only DOI with the same keywords. To get this result,  the partion by clause is the only way?

Comment: @Gwynbleidd . . . There is a big difference between a subset/superset approach and an exact match.  I've edit the answer to offer two solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `listagg` as follows:

```
With cte as
(Select t.doi, listagg(keyword,',') within group (order by keyword) as keyword
from your_table t
Group by t.id)
Select distinct t1.doi f_doi, t2.id s_doi, t1.keyword
From cte t1 join cte t2
On t1.adventure = t2.adventure
And t1.doi < t2.doi;
```

Comment: With this query I have to know in advance which are the keywords, right?
The problem is that I need to write a "general query", whitout indicate the keywords.